# Batch file is working fine when double-click but not from outlook rules

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, outlook, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit

I wrote a batch file(code below) to launch my .vbs file using 64-bit mode. Created an outlook rule to trigger the batch file when specific mail appears in my mailbox.
"Sleep 5" is being executed properly but the step to launch .vbs file is not working from Outlook. The same batch file is working as expected when double click.

Code:
Sleep 5
Start C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript.exe "myfile.vbs"

Note: I've placed "myfile.vbs" in my Users folder without which .....\SysWOW64\cscript.exe wont launch the .vbs file

Please suggest

Comment: Why launch it in 64 bit?

Comment: @NizonRox, they aren't! @Pavan, the SysWOW64 directory is the container for the 32-bit files, not the 64-bit which are in the System32 directory. Also I would suggest, if you feel the need to use `Start`, to try `Start "Title" "your command"` as mentioned in the help; **Start /?**.